# HTML Form with PHP Action

Tags: php, html, variables, authentication

Given the code below, what happens after the submit button is pressed and the login_process.php completes its task? Does the HTML continue on from the point where  comment is?

If the answer is Yes, then what would be the best way to pass the following from the PHP page?

- Authentication passed or failed
- Variables from the PHP page (profile info)

Style section was deleted for brevity sake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Login Page</title>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Begin Page Content -->
        <div id="container">
            <form action="login_process.php" method="post">
                <label for="loginmsg" style="color:hsla(0,100%,50%,0.5); font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                    <?php  echo @$_GET['msg'];?>
                </label>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <div id="lower">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </div><!--/ lower-->
            </form>
        </div><!--/ container-->
        <!-- End Page Content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"what happens after the submit button is pressed and the login_process.php completes its task? Does the HTML continue on from the point where comment is?"* - A: It goes from form to handler. The form has done its job and now the handler takes over; why would it continue doing something?

Comment: So once PHP takes control it won't return to the HTML that called it?

Comment: You also have no PHP in there and we don't know if you're using that in the same file or two. Edit: only if you tell it to.

Comment: The web is stateless so it can't remember where it was before a request was made (unless you go through the trouble of saving the previous state somewhere manually).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What happens after the submit button is pressed and the login_process.php completes its task depends on what you want your "login_process.php" file's code to do. You may redirect it or simply print hello or validate your form getting its field's values or whatever you want to get done.

For authentication, 
1 - get your form's field values via $_POST[] array
2 - validate the data received with your database values.
3 - take action accordingly.

Take a look at [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2016/04/php-login-system-with-pdo-connection.html) tutorial which will guide you of how to do authentication in PHP.

Comment: *"Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm) tutorial which will guide you of how to do authentication in PHP."* - You should at the very least, warn them that that page is only a basic example and should not be used on a live site unless a prepared statement is used.

Comment: Thanks for that! Perhaps my explanation wasn't detailed enough. I guess, I'm assuming that the PHP process acts like a function call, but I now getting the feeling that is doesn't do that and once it has completed, I would redirect to login_successful.html or login_denied.html for the next step in my web site. Can I pass variables from the PHP to next HTML (whether its success or failure) ?

Comment: You can pass to your HTML via query string but that will just append in URL and you wont be able to use PHP code to display or work on any of values passed in query string, you may use Javascript to fetch values from your URL query string that you passed from your php controller. However I suggest to use PHP files instead of HTML if you want to pass values to and from.

Comment: That tutorial also uses the deprecated `session_register()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php - Why on earth would you suggest such a tutorial? Not to mention safe authentication password hashing. IMHO, that is a bad example.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've edited link. About hashing things, the user who posted the question above seems novice. He first needs to clear his understanding of basic login/register things and then proceed for security concerns

Comment: @sysquare Lordie, sorry to say but that is even worse. mysql_ is deprecated and deleted as of PHP 7.0 - I know you're trying to help but you need to find the ones that use a prepared statement and `password_hash()`. They are so much safer to work with, given the world we live in now ;-)

Comment: Ask questionnaire if he uses PDO or even knows anything related, answer will be "NO".  
He himself should google out things rather than requiring me to search tutorials for him. Am not pointing out "best strategies" for login thing coz he didnt ask for "best approach for authentication". All he needs to know is how to validate form values with Database values.

Comment: @user3308131 You **must not use that tutorial**.  It is absolutely horrible and does things **wrong** at every step. It is like a tutorial on how to write the worst possible PHP code you can. Sysquare, this link is *so bad* that it is borderline irresponsible of you to be linking new-to-PHP users to it and implying that it is a good resource to learn from. The only reason that link still exists is that it's built on Wordpress, and the author didn't actually use any of his own horrible code in the authentication system.